# How can I trace the "names" of all the parts of a 3d model

Tags: flash, trace, flare3d

I'm loading an exported 3dmodel from Flare3d successfully into Flash. I'm able to trace the "name" of the different parts of the model with a `MouseCollision()`.

The goal:

extract all the model parts names/part number dynamically without 
the mousecollision.

*I would like to retrieve the same data before the model is added to the stage.

I expect to output all the 3d model's parts names to then manipulate the data for my application use. I want to do this dynamically for ease of updates to the 3d models.

I have traced the main scene: Scene3D which I'm using the 
`scene = new Viewer3D(this)`.

the output returns [object Camera3D], [object Flare3DLoader]

This is what is currently working only with a mousecollision:

```
private function updateEvent(e: Event): void {
        if (mouse.test(Input3D.mouseX, Input3D.mouseY)) {

        // get access to the first and closest collision.
        var over: Pivot3D = mouse.data[0].mesh;

        if (over != last) {

         // name of 3d part is traced.
        trace("mouse in", over.name);
        }
        over.rotateY(10);
        last = over;
        Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.BUTTON;
        } else {
          if (last) {
        trace("mouse out", last.name);
        }
        last = null;
        Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.AUTO;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

private function updateEvent(e: Event): void {
  for each (var n:Surface3D in holder.surfaces)

```
            {

            trace(n.name);

            }
```

}